# How to generate Visual Studio Projects programmatically in my windows application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I'm developing some generator application and I need to generate Visual Studio Projects with some configuration (Like a MVC 3 project), is there anyway to do so? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Visual Studio` project file is simply an XML document.  So as long as you get the syntax and structure correct, you can generate it any way you please.

You can also programmatically create project files using the `Visual Studio Automation Object Model (DTE)`.  There is a good getting started guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org) to see how they are doing this - they do generate Visual Studio Projects among many others and have the source available. So yes, it should be possible.